# Unexpected output after linking

Tags: c

I have two C files:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int n);

double array[2] = { 0.001, 1.0001 };

int main()
{
    int val = sum(2);
    printf("%d\n", val);
    return 0;
}
```

sum.c

```
extern int array[2];

int sum(int n)
{
    int i, ret = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ret += array[i];
    }

    return ret;
}
```

I compile and link the files and then run the executable, but I am getting some unexpected output:

```
306318409
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: What is it then `int array[]` or `double array[]` ?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with linking, but with the inconsistency of variables. If you want to add double numbers you need to have a double variables. I am also not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve. 
`extern double array[2];`
`double ret=0;`
`double sum(int n);`
`double val=sum(2);`

`printf("%f\n",val) ;`

Comment: **indent your code!**

Answer (score 1):

C Standard section 6.2.7/2 says

> All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall have compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

So anything could have happened.  That's what you get when you lie to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

This really helps to make out the difference between compiling and linking .

When these two files where compiled :

main.c

- implicitly declares a sum() function with return type as int*.
- Has an array variable of type double* in it's list of variables

sum.c :

- externed variable array allowed by compiler to get a value at link time and added to it's list of symbols .
- defines a function sum which now uses the variable array with type as int* whose information was maintained by the compiler independently for this program that was externed  .

Now at link time :

- sum() call in main.c gets resolved from sum.c
- sum.c had maintained the type of array variable as int* , while the extern variable was resolved by the double* type ,which however does not change the behaviour of variable array decided in sum() definition at compile time .

An array of doubles  is stored with each in 8 bytes , while the sum() function assumed it would be stored per 4 bytes . So array[0] read the first 4 bytes and array[1] read the next 4 bytes , while however the number 0.001 in main.c from it's array[0] was itself stored in 8 bytes , leading to this undefined behavior.